# make direction using Google maps and Android with multi destination?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

how can i make direction using Google maps and Android with multi destination?

example, start: town A

- dest. 1: town C
- dest. 2: town B
- dest. 3: town F

Comment: I think he wants to draw a route starting from town A to another town(not specified) having town C, town B and town F on the way on google maps.

Comment: are you using the maps app (via intent) or your own mapview or maps via the web?  If you are using google maps via the web you will have the easiest solution.

Comment: also seems to be a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039647/showing-a-route-between-two-points-with-multiple-waypoints/11069254#11069254

Comment: @ MikeIsrael can we do this via Intent or not?

Answer (score 0):

Best i've found so far is to install boat browser and run in desktop mode. Then sign in to google maps in that browser and enter your search (as you would on a PC).

After you've done that, within androids google maps, you can now select "my places" and "recent" and select your route.

I just wish thee was a easier way of doing it.