# URI for Google Maps Intent with waypoints

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I would like to add to my app ability to open Google Maps app with more than 2 points but I can only set start point and end point. How to add waypoints?
I've tried uri as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13565504/3626048 but it's not working. In Google Maps doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents there's also nothing about it. Is it even possible to add waypoints to Google Maps intent?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @kaho, for this "I think you can use +to:waypoint after the destination address."

This works for me with multiple way points:

```
  RealmList<LocationEntity> list = routeEntity.getStops();
  ArrayList<Map<String,Object>> latLang = new ArrayList<>();

  for (LocationEntity location: list){
    latLang.add(location.toMap());
  }


  String jsonURL = "https://maps.google.com/maps?";
  final StringBuffer sBuf = new StringBuffer(jsonURL);
  sBuf.append("saddr=");
  sBuf.append(destLat);
  sBuf.append(',');
  sBuf.append(destLong);
  sBuf.append("&daddr=");
  sBuf.append(sourceLat);
  sBuf.append(',');
  sBuf.append(sourceLong);
  sBuf.append("+to:");
  sBuf.append(latLang.get(0).get("latitude"));
  sBuf.append(',');
  sBuf.append(latLang.get(0).get("longitude"));
  sBuf.append("+to:");
  sBuf.append(latLang.get(1).get("latitude"));
  sBuf.append(',');
  sBuf.append(latLang.get(1).get("longitude"));
  sBuf.append("+to:");
  sBuf.append(latLang.get(2).get("latitude"));
  sBuf.append(',');
  sBuf.append(latLang.get(2).get("longitude"));
  sBuf.append("+to:");
  sBuf.append(latLang.get(3).get("latitude"));
  sBuf.append(',');
  sBuf.append(latLang.get(3).get("longitude"));
  sBuf.append("+to:");
  sBuf.append(latLang.get(4).get("latitude"));
  sBuf.append(',');
  sBuf.append(latLang.get(4).get("longitude"));

  // sBuf.append("&sensor=true&mode=DRIVING");
  sBuf.append("&key=");
  sBuf.append("Your_API_KEY");

  MISLog.printDebug(sBuf);

  Intent sendLocationToMap = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse(sBuf.toString()));
  startActivity(sendLocationToMap);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `+to:waypoint` after the destination address. For example:

https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=San+Francisco&daddr=GooglePlex+Mountain+View+to:San+Jose

Or:

https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=San+Francisco&daddr=GooglePlex+Mountain+View+to:Google+Building+45+to:San+Jose

Comment: It's not working as Google Maps Intent, when Maps app launches it says that Google Maps can't open link :(

Comment: Oh yea... I think I heard someone said that before on ios's Google map

Comment: Is there any other way?