# Send waypoint to Android Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can I send some Waypoint(lat & long) from my Android app to Google Map using intent, and see roads on Google Map? Does this feature free? Can I take a picture from it programmatically?
Something like https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/directions-waypoints

Comment: Try using this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40014802/7989770

FYI: you need to get a api from Google Developers console which you need to update timely.

Comment: Thank's. In Developers console what service will be used: `Google Maps Android API` or `Google Place API for Android`?

Comment: Google place api

Comment: You can use Google Maps URLs. Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46910653/5140781